# [Vue Router warn]: Error with push/replace State TypeError: history[(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)] is not a function

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to set up vue router (Vue 3 + Vue Router 4) but I keep getting the following errors:

```
[Vue Router warn]: Error with push/replace State TypeError: history[(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)] is not a function

[Vue Router warn]: Unexpected error when starting the router: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'back')

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'back')
```

Here's my main.ts:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import store, { storeKey } from "./store/index";

// styling
import "./scss/base.scss";
import router from "./router";

createApp(App).use(router).use(store, storeKey).mount("#app");
```

And here's my router.ts file:

```
import {
  createRouter,
  createWebHashHistory,
  Router,
  RouteRecordRaw,
} from "vue-router";
import Home from "@/components/Home.vue";
import FetchInfo from "@/components/FetchInfo.vue";

const routes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: "/requests",
    name: "Requests",
    component: FetchInfo,
  },
];

const router: Router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(),
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

How do I resolve the above error?

I'm using the following versions:

> - "vue": "^3.2.13",
> - "vue-router": "^4.0.15",
> - "webpack": "^5.72.1",
> - "webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.0"

Comment: @dotNET Yes, I ended up creating the router as so:

const router: Router = createRouter({
  history: createMemoryHistory(),
  routes,
});

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone lands here and is using Vue Router together with Office.js, be advised that there is a bug in Office.js code where it sets `window.history.replaceState` and `window.history.pushState` to `null`, which causes Vue Router to break and throw the error mentioned in the OP. In my case, it also caused the page to keep reloading over and over in quick succession.

A related issue and a PR are available [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/pull/2808), waiting to be merged, as of Dec 2022.

Comment: Still an error in office.js as of november 2023. The workaround code on the linked issue page worked for me with a Vue.

Answer (score 1):

The following bit fixed the problem:

const router: Router = createRouter({
***history: createMemoryHistory(),***
routes,
});